# Value access in C++

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt4

HI,

I have two clases A and B,
 Here A is inheriting B and now i want to access a variable in B from A, I included A header in B and tried to access but showing some error in QObject.

Is it possible to acces like this.. Please help

Comment: Please post exact error and code!

Comment: Some error in `QObject` point to a problem with the Qt part of the problem, more than a problem with the C++ side of it. In general, if the member in `base` is public or protected, all derived classes can access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure i get your Q correctly....

```
class A {
public:
  int nValueA;
protected:
  int nValueB;
private:
  int nValueC;
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B();
    int x, y, z;
}; 
B::B(): 
x(nValueA), //-->OK
y(nValueB), //-->OK
z(nValueC)  //-->error due to child can't inherit parent's private member
{}

void main(){
  B object;
  object.nValueA = 888; //--> valid
  object.nValueB = 888; //--> error since protected member is not accessible
  object.nValueC = 888; //--> error since private member is not accessible
}
```

Possible solution:

```
class A {
public:
  int nValueA;
  int nValueB;
  int nValueC;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your member variable `private`? Then you cannot, declare it `protected`.